# CSS Override for specific content boxes in dotcms?

Tags: css, dotcms

Is there a way to have only the css within my current content box rendered? If I want the css from other content boxes/widgets to be ignored - is this possible in dotcms?

Comment: Are you talking about the CSS for the admin (the edit buttons etc) or the CSS for the website itself.

Comment: @koenpeters the CSS for the admin. Where it says "Edit Content". I was wondering if I could write css for a specific div or something in a content box and have it ignore the rest of the site's css. Probably not, but I figured it was worth asking.

Comment: You'd have to change dotCMS's CSS itself. I don't think this is something that can be easily done. Maybe if you describe in more detail what you'd like to accomplish (the end goal) I can come up with a workaround.